# Principle and generalization of proportional-resonance controller

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, resonance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7NN9C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can introduce the model of \$u(s)\$ into the controller \$K(s)\$ to realize high accuracy control.

- \$u(t) = 1\$, i.e. \$u(s) = 1/s\$. We use \$K(s) = K_p + \frac{K_i}{s}\$ (PI controller) to realize zero static error.
- \$u(t) = \sin(\omega t)\$, i.e. \$u(s) = \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\$. We use \$K(s) = K_p + \frac{K}{s^2+\omega^2}\$ to realize zero static error.

Now my problem is that, does this work for **any other** \$u(t)\$? Such as \$u(t) = \exp(\alpha t)\$?

P.S. I learnt that the high accuracy of PI or proportional-resonance controller is **high gain**. I can understand this for DC input (\$u(t) = 1\$) or sine input. But if this kind of controller works for other input, how to understand the **gain** here?

Comment: Put a "\" before each instance of "$" to get Latex working properly. Why do you call a PI controller a "proportional-resonance" controller?

Comment: @Andyaka proportional-resonance controller (PR controller) is the controller shown in the 2nd bullet